# How do I convert Oracle query to criteria query?

Tags: oracle

```
select l.city,
       l.street_address,
       c.country_name,
       r.region_name 
from HR.locations l join HR.countries c using (country_id)
                    join HR.regions r   using (region_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer by using simple logic.

private static void getLocations(Session session){

```
    Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Locations.class);
    Criteria countries= query.createCriteria("country");
    Criteria regions =countries.createCriteria("region");



    List<Locations> locations = regions.list();

    for(Locations loc: locations){
        System.out.println(loc.getCity() + " "+loc.getStreetAddress()+" "+loc.getCountry().getCountryName()
                +" "+loc.getCountry().getRegion().getRegionName());
    }


}
```